# Java Question RobotSim on moving through 2d string map with enum commands, certain characters & constraints

Tags: java, robotics

I am working on a project that is a basic robot application.  I am using a few classes and enums and am to use my enums to move around, and here I am a bit confused..
So I am working on my main class right now -Robo.  Here is the uml for Robo/what I am doing just for reference:

```
-currenLocate : Point
- directionFacing : FacingDirection
-map : FloorMap
- Carryingthing : boolean
-successfullyDropped : boolean

+Robo(map : FloorMap)
+Robo(map : FloorMap,currentLocatiom.  
: Point)
+move(command : RoboCommand) : void
+iscarryingThing() : boolean
+isSuccessfullyDropped() :boolean.
```

Ok, so I am working on my move(), and I need to take into consideration my enums, FacingDirection(All 4 directions), MapObject (items to pick up) and then my movement enum(Forward, left, right, pickup and drop).  And then my two booleans.

So I know I need to get my direction facing and take that into consideration when entering a command by my enum, but what do you suppose would be my best course of action?  I am thinking else and else if and some &&, and an array perhaps but now I'm not totally sure.  I have to do a forwardfromup, forwardfromdown, etc. I can give more info if needed, but I don't want to bog this post down with too much if I can help it.  =D.  I appreciate your time and thanks in advance for any assistance/tips.

Comment: It will be helpful for others to guide you , if you have already wrote some code and ask for improvements in the approach.

Comment: What is the purpose of successfullyDropped? Can an item also be unsuccessfully dropped? Will it stay true forever after dropping anything?

Comment: Can you explain further on forwardfromup, forwardfromdown, and their correlation between the directionFacing? How would the robot move, on a 2d plane?

Comment: Hi all, SSotheby's pod can only be dropped in a drop zone, so thats the point of successfullydropped.  And if my bot is facing down then the moveforwardfromdown would be activate. concerning the xy axis of my bots point.

Comment: If ((command == BotCommand..FORWARD) && ( 
    ( directionFacing == FacingDirection.LEFT))[         
     getinitialbotLocatoon  (x, y--);                    return.      
     FloorMap_Object.BOT.currentLocation.        and then I have an else if for the rest following that staging of code.  Its compiling fine but as far as functionality....im not sure if im doing the right thing.

Answer (score 1):

You are not giving complete information so some assumptions:

- The FloorMap represents a 2D area of Points with x,y coordinates (0-based)
- A Point represents a single x,y coordinate and optionally a MapObject
- FacingDirections are up/down (y-axis) and left/right (x-axis)
- Robo will always be at a point on the floor facing a certain direction
- A RoboCommand can be: move forward, turn left, turn right, pick up, drop

So for example Robo can be in the FloorMap at Point (4,2) facing up:

```
........
....a...
........
...^....
........
```

The point at (5,4) holds a MapObject (a)

To get the MapObject, Robo would need to execute the commands:

```
forward, forward, right, forward, pick up
```

So much for the context.

To start implementing this, you would need to create your domain classes:

- FloorMap, Point, MapObject
- FacingDirection
- RoboCommand

You could implement the commands following the [command pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern) using an enum (although I prefer separate classes for this).

```
public enum RoboCommand {

    FORWARD() {
        void execute(Robo robo) {    
            // determine the new coordinates by adding the appropriate deltas
            long x = robo.getCurrentLocation().getX() + robo.getFacingDirection().deltaX();
            long y = robo.getCurrentLocation().getY() + robo.getFacingDirection().deltaY();
            // get (or create) the matching Point from the floorMap
            robo.getFloorMap().getPoint(x, y);
            // move Robo to the new point
            robo.setCurrentLocation(point);
        }
    }, RIGHT {
        void execute(Robo robo) {
            //use the left/right logic in FacingDirection
            FacingDirection direction = robo.getFacingDirection().right();
            // face Robo in the new direction
            robo.setFacingDirection(direction);
        }
    }, LEFT {
        void execute(Robo robo) {
            robo.setFacingDirection(robo.getFacingDirection().left());
        }
    }, PICK_UP {
        void execute(Robo robo) {
            // get the optional item from the current Point
            robo.getCurrentLocation().getItem()
                .ifPresent(item -> {                        
                    // remove it from the Point
                    robo.getCurrentLocation().setItem(null);
                    // add it to Robo
                    robo.setCarried(item);
                });
            
        }
    }, DROP {
        void execute(Robo robo) {
            // get the optional carried item from Robo
            robo.getCarried()                    
                .ifPresent(item -> {
                    // remove it from Robo
                    robo.setCarried(null);
                    // add it to the Point
                    robo.getCurrentLocation().setItem(item);
                });
        }
    };

    abstract void execute(Robo robo);
    
}
```

Some thoughts about the domain design.

I would like to design the FloorMap as a set, rather than an array, of Points. Only Points which hold items or have been visited by Robo will exist in the set.

```
class FloorMap {
    Set<Point> points = new HashSet<>();       

    Point getPoint(long x, long y) {
        // looks up the point, creating a new one if necessary
        return points.stream()
            .filter(p -> p.getX() == x && p.getY() == y)
            .findAny()
            .orElse(newPoint(x, y));
    } 

    private Point newPoint(long x, long y) {
        Point point = new Point(x, y);
        points.add(point);
        return point;
    }
}
```

If Robo walks around a lot, one could envision a clean up algorithm which removes empty Points. One needs to think of a way to stop the Point that is currently visited by Robo to be cleaned up.

The Robo will have a Point as its currentLocation, referring to a Point in the FloorMap, and an optional MapObject:

```
class Robo {
    Point currentLocation;
    FacingDirection facingDirection;
    MapObject carried;

    Robo(FloorMap floorMap) {
        currentLocation = floorMap.getPoint(0, 0);
        facingDirection = FacingDirection.UP;
    }

    Optional<MapObject> getCarried() {
        return Optional.ofNullable(carried);
    } 
}
```

A Point will have an optional item:

```
class Point{
    long x;
    long y;
    MapObject item;

    Point(long x, long y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    Optional<MapObject> getItem() {
        return Optional.ofNullable(mapObject);
    } 
}
```

The FacingDirection enum in my design has delta methods to indicate the changes to x and y coordinates and left/right methods which return a new FacingDirection:

```
enum FacingDirection {
    UP() {
        int deltaX() {
            return 0;
        }
        int deltaY()  {
            return 1;
        }
        FacingDirection left() {
            return LEFT;
        }
        FacingDirection right() {
            return RIGHT;
        }
    },
    RIGHT() {
        int deltaX() {
            return 1;
        }
        int deltaY()  {
            return 0;
        }
        FacingDirection left() {
            return UP;
        }
        FacingDirection right() {
            return DOWN;
        }
    },
    // etc...

    abstract int deltaX();
    abstract int deltaY();
    abstract FacingDirection left();
    abstract FacingDirection right();
}
```

Comment: Hi Adriaan, yep.  I am new at this, and you're assumptions are correct.  =)

Comment: I do have a getdelta set up in my facingdirection enumenum, sorry I left that out above  How should I add that in to the directions above taking into account directionFacing in my move() (ie moveforwardfrom right,, etc.)  And thank you so much for your help.

Comment: Would it be better if I added my class diagram or full uml?  Sorry, I was trying to find a balance between too much info and enough for the part im twisting myself up on.

Comment: I think you should stay away from complicated concepts like 'moveforwardfromright'. See my design above. The 'UML' you presented is not very clear, has many typos and redundancy and does not offer any explanations. I hardly ever use UML since it is not a concise way to express my thoughts. The first part of my answer (up to 'So much for the context') shows how I tend to describe such a problem.